# Using state with componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, state, react-lifecycle

I want to fetch data that returns successfully after componentDidMount, but before there is an error that singer.data is undefined:

```
// imports
export default class LookSinger extends Component {
    state = {
        singer: {}
    }
    componentDidMount () {
        let { singer } = this.props.location.state;
        singer = singer.replace(/ /g,"+");
        const fetchData = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(
                `http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=${singer}&api_key=a3c9fd095f275f4139c33345e78741ed&format=json`
            );
            const data = await response.json();
            this.setState({
                singer: data
            })
          } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
          }
        }
        fetchData();
    }
      render() {
          let singer = this.state.singer
        return(
            <div>
                {console.log(singer.artist.name)} // gives undefined but after fetching artist.name absolutely exists
            </div>
        )
      }
}
```

Url is:http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=Ariana+Grande&api_key=a3c9fd095f275f4139c33345e78741ed&format=json

Comment: ```singer``` is an object, shouldn't it be a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

> {console.log(singer.artist.name)}

In the initial render, `singer.artist` is undefined and if you call `singer.artist.name` it will throw error. `name of undefined`.... You just need to wait for data to fetch and update the state.

Try like this

```
export default class LookSinger extends Component {
  state = {
    singer: {}
  }
  componentDidMount () {
    let { singer } = this.props.location.state;
    singer = singer.replace(/ /g,"+");
    const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(`http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=${singer}&api_key=a3c9fd095f275f4139c33345e78741ed&format=json`);
        const data = await response.json();
        this.setState({ singer: data })
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
      }
    }
    fetchData();
  }
  render() {
    const { singer } = this.state
    if (!singer.artist) { // <-- Check if the data is present or not.
      return <div>Loding singer info...</div>
    }
    return(
      <div>
        <h1>{singer.artist.name}</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do `let singer = this.state` but there's no `this.setState({ singer: ... })` in your code. Instead of `this.setState({ data })`, try `this.setState({ singer: data })`

Comment: can you send me the URL of your request then I can see the JSON result ?

Answer (score 0):

Set you state as below and,

```
        const data = await response.json();
        this.setState({
            singer: data
        })
```

and you can log it out likes this,

```
        console.log(this.state.singer)
```

Comment: What is your problem now?

Comment: The problem is same

Comment: Your problem is "singer.data is undefined:", but you don't call as singer.data is anywhere in your code.